# How to stop an AppleScript from repeating itself

Tags: macos, applescript, mdm

I have an AppleScript that addresses issues with out-of-sync Active Directory passwords on macOS. It resets the secure token on a given account by disabling and then re-enabling the token.  I run it as a Self Service item in Jamf.  The problem is that, once the script has finished, it loops back to the beginning and starts to run again.  Not sure why it doesn't quit after the token has been re-enabled.  If I run it in Script Editor, it doesn't loop, but from Jamf's Self Service, it loops back to the beginning after the second verification.  Thanks for any help with this one.

```
set the_folder to (path to users folder)
tell application "Finder"
    set foldernames to name of every folder of the_folder
end tell
set theChosenOne to choose from list foldernames with prompt "Select user needing a password sync"
display dialog "Password for " & theChosenOne default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue" with hidden answer
set thePassword to quoted form of text returned of the result
--disable secure token
do shell script "sysadminctl interactive -secureTokenOff " & theChosenOne & " -password " & thePassword
set theVerification to do shell script "sysadminctl interactive -secureTokenStatus " & theChosenOne & " 2>&1 | awk -F']' '{print $2}'"
display dialog theVerification

set the_folder to (path to users folder)
tell application "Finder"
    set foldernames to name of every folder of the_folder
end tell
set theChosenOne to choose from list foldernames with prompt "Re-select user needing a password sync"
display dialog "Password for " & theChosenOne default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue" with hidden answer
set thePassword to quoted form of text returned of the result
--re-enable secure token
do shell script "sysadminctl interactive -secureTokenOn " & theChosenOne & " -password " & thePassword
set theVerification to do shell script "sysadminctl interactive -secureTokenStatus " & theChosenOne & " 2>&1 | awk -F']' '{print $2}'"
display dialog theVerification
return
```

Comment: Just double-checking - have you posted the full code? And, as far as you can tell, is your AppleScript running **exactly** as expected (except for the looping issue)?

Comment: Thanks Monomeeth. Yes, this is the complete code for the policy that loops (that policy is triggered in Jamf by a bash script that verifies that the account attempting to disable/re-enable the secure token does possess a token itself).  When I run it in Script Editor, it presents the list of users accounts, verifies the account's token was disabled, presents the list again to re-sync, verifies again, and quits.  When I run in the Jamf's Self Service, after the final verification, it presents the first list of user accounts again.

Comment: It turned out that when I had split it up into two policies in Jamf, I hadn't removed the original script from the first policy after creating the second policy, so the script was looping because it was actually running twice.

Comment: That's great - glad you got it sorted! :)